# LESS, how to extend a parent's rules to its direct child?

Tags: css, less

I just want to give a children the exact same properties as its parent (cascading doesn't always work when you have to work on already existing css)

I thought this would work but it doesn't produce anything.

```
.colorTheming() {
    article {
        h2 {
            .txt(@themeColor,2.4,@gravBold);
            > span {
                &:extend(article h2);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Of course I could do it like h2, h2 span {}, but I was wondering if there was a way to do that more elegantly

Comment: While this may be a real Less problem. From CSS perspective, surely you're on the wrong way

Comment: well wysiwyg are a pain to deal with so I have to cover everything that it can output.. that is h2 with span, h2 without span, h2 with span and inline styling, obscure .css from previous site version that I didn't see, etc. do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: @topleft: That extend statement should work as long as there are no problems elsewhere. And in my opinion, `h2, h2 > span` **is the most elegant way**.

Comment: I agree with Harry here. `h2, h2 > span` is much more elegant as it's a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` is your friend:

```
.colorTheming() {
    article {
        h2 {
            > span,
            & {
                .txt(@themeColor,2.4,@gravBold);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The extra `&` is not really required here because OP is trying to extend the properties that are present under `h2` selector to `h2 > span` also. Why would you extend the properties of the `h2` again to the same `h2` using the parent selector?

Comment: I didn't mention the `:extend` and corrected the code to a better version, which still works with the `&` because of its possibility.

Comment: I don't wish to argue but you can see that the original version which you posted did have the `:extend`. And even here `h2, h2 > span` is much better than `h2 { > span, & {}}`.

Comment: Why is it better? I think that's your personal and own opinion. Technically both is correct and usable.

Comment: It is better because there is absolutely no need to add an extra line of code and involve the parent selector when it can be done without it.

Comment: However my version is better extensible e. g. if you want to use the same for  the `h3`, possibly… The shortest way is not the best everytime.